# Jquery Ajax call to PHP sometimes appends data twice

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I've written a script using jQuery Ajax and PHP which should fetch data from a MySQL database and append the result as an `<option>` within a `<select>` element.

The code should work like this:

When the name in the text input changes, all options of class `.modpick` are removed from the `<select>` element. An Ajax call then connects to a PHP script which checks whether there is more than one record in the database with the same name. If not, another Ajax call connects to another PHP script which pulls the data from the database and echos it out as an `<option>` element. The Ajax callback then appends the data from the PHP script to the `<select>` element.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the `<option>` element is appended twice, so when you open the `<select>` element it displays the same `<option>` twice. What is really confusing is that this doesn't happen all the time - only occassionally.

I can't figure out why this is happening, especially as it doesn't happen every time, nor can I identify whether it's a problem with the jQuery or the PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', "#uploadname", function () {
    uploadname = $(this).val();
    $('.modpick').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadnames.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            uploadname: uploadname
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#checkulinputs').html(data);
            uploademailcheck = $('#emailupcheckinput').val();

            if (uploademailcheck == 'nochoose') {
                uploademail = '';
                $('#ulemailcheck').slideUp();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "uploadnamesmodules.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        uploadname: uploadname
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(data).appendTo($('#uploadmoduleselect'));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
})
```

PHP:

```
include_once('../../dbconnect.php');

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uploadname']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM marking_assignments WHERE name = '$name' ORDER BY unit ASC";
$details = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = $details->fetch_assoc()){
 $modnamequery = "SELECT mod_name FROM modules WHERE module = '" . $row['unit'] . "'";
 $modname = $conn->query($modnamequery);
 while ($line = $modname->fetch_assoc()){
  $descrip = $line['mod_name'];
  }

echo '<option  value="' . $row['unit'] . '" id="m' . $row['unit'] . '" class="modpick">' . $descrip . '</option>'; 

}
```

HTML (After query has been run - note the two identical `<option>` elements):

```
<form id="uploadfeedbackform" method="POST" action="uploadfeedback.php">
  <input type="text" class="inputs" name="upload_name" id="uploadname" placeholder="Enter Student Name" />

  <div id="checkulinputs"></div>
  <div id="ulemailcheck" class="emailchecker"></div>

  <select id="uploadmoduleselect" name="uploadmodules">
     <option  value="choose" class="choosemod">Select Module</option>
     <option value="405" id="m405" class="modpick">4.05 Managing Health & Safety at Work</option>
     <option value="405" id="m405" class="modpick">4.05 Managing Health & Safety at 
  </select>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your `change` handler can be called multiple times, leading to multiple ajax requests which (quite rightly) fire their success callbacks.
Ajax requests will just queue up rather than replacing the previous request, leading to a possible queue of pending callbacks.

You can store the ajax request in a variable and `abort()` the request in the event that your handler somehow gets called twice.

Example:

```
var myRequest;

//in your change handler...
if (myRequest)
{
    myRequest.abort();
}
myRequest = $.ajax({...});
```

This way there will only be one active ajax request at a time, and only one success callback that is pending.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)